# Template is rendering Grid field output incorrectly within an <a href""> tag

Tags: relationships, grid, links, page-uri

I have a Homepage channel setup with a `homepage` field group.

Within the field group, there is a `homepage_slider` Grid field and within that Grid there is an `image` and `page_link` field.

When called in via the following `{homepage_slider:image}` renders correctly (the image shows without issue.

However, using the following:

```
<a href="{homepage_slider:page_link}{homepage_slider:page_link:pager}{/homepage_slider:page_link}">
```

Renders only as:

```
<a href="{/">
```

Outside of the  it appears to work and display the correct `page_uri`.

Looking at the syntax, it looks like it should be OK and I've trawled through the other settings inside the CMS without much luck in terms of debugging. I've also incrementally removing elements of the template and the problem occurs as soon as the element goes inside of the `<a href="">` tag.

EDIT:
Here is the full code block:

```
{homepage_slider}
<div class="slide">
    <a href="{homepage_slider:page_link}{homepage_slider:page_link:page_uri}{/homepage_slider:page_link}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{homepage_slider:image}" width="960" height="450" crop="yes"}</a>
</div>
{/homepage_slider}
```

(Note: Running EE 2.8.1)

Comment: Could you post the full template code for the homepage slider block. from opening homepage_slide to closing tag

Comment: Sean, updated original post with code block, as requested.

Comment: Why is the page_link field a tag pair? What type of cell is this? I would think your link should work with href="{homepage_slider:page_link}"

Comment: Just realised that I didn't mention the `page_link` field is a Relationship field within the Grid. My apologies.

Comment: You call the grid field homepage_slide in your post, but then reference homepage_slider (with an 'r') - Which is correct?

Comment: Romans - that was a mis-type, I'll correct it. It should be `homepage_slider`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the page_link is a tag pair or what page_link:pager is. Could you elaborate on that?

It looks to me like the correct code should be:

```
{homepage_slider}
<div class="slide">
    <a href="{homepage_slider:page_link}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{homepage_slider:image}" width="960" height="450" crop="yes"}</a>
</div>
{/homepage_slider}
```

Comment: Sean, we need the `page_uri` in there so that the specified product can be linked. We've used similar setups to this previously without issue.

Comment: is the relationship cell playa or native - if playa can you set a var_prefix? do you want page_uri or page_url?

Comment: It's a native Relationship field. It's not the first time we've had issues with the native Grid/Relationship fields, I was just hoping we've gone code blind and missed something.